# Intermediate Value Theorem and average speed.

Tags: calculus

[Roots of Unity](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/math-on-the-run/) writes about using the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that a runner could have run a one mile segment at the average speed that she ran the entire race.  I say "could have" because she goes on to provide a counter example.

But my question is, how can I use the IVT to show that a runner ran a one mile segment at a speed of $\bar{v}$, her average speed from the beginning of the race to the end?  What function are we using the IVT on?

I was thinking $$\bar{v}(t,a) = \dfrac{v(t+a)-v(t)}{a} \quad a\neq 0 ,v(t+a)-v(t) = 1 $$

but then do I apply IVT on $a$ or $t$?

Comment: How do you know that the runner ran a mile at her average speed? The intermediate value theorem only implies that her instantaneous speed at some point is her average speed.

Comment: I think that is the MEAN value theorem.  This is kind of what I am getting at.

Comment: You're right, but either way the intermediate value theorem still only implies that the function achieves each intermediate value at a point, not a full one mile interval.

Comment: You can use the intermediate value theorem to show that her instantaneous speed at some point is her average speed as well, because clearly her minimum velocity on the interval is less than her average velocity on the interval and is in turn less than her maximum velocity.